# Solution to dynamic configure Spring aplication

Tags: spring, jsp, jakarta-ee, spring-mvc

Our application is developed using Spring framework, however, some of the configuration(i.e. database url in a `properties` file) need to define dynamically. So here comes the questions:

1. Is it possible by `Spring` itself? i don't think it is quite practical but still worth to ask
2. If answer to 1. is No, then i am thinking about using JSP to achieve the job. So how can we let Spring application and traditional JSP application lives within same web application(possibly with minimal coding compromise, really don't like to get another 20 lib jars and 50 classes to handle such task)? two  in `web.xml`? Then how do we manage the coding structure?

I am kind of a newbie on such topic. So any suggestion is appreciated.

### UPDATE

I think I made confusion here. What I am trying to design is an UI or something like that can change configuration settings and write it into a properies file. It is OK to ask user to restart the application. But if we let regular JSP to work on this then it is OK to let `JSP` and `Spring` live under the same web.xml? How about coding structure?

Comment: Why can't you use a `PropertyPlaceholderConfigurator`? How would using a JSP application help?

Comment: @Dave Newton Can `PropertyPlaceholderConfigurator` do dynamic configuration and write back into the properties file?

Comment: no, it can;t. Hence you will need to store in a database via an app. But you need a permanent database url,for the other settings

Comment: Why would the app's DB configuration change enough to warrant being able to update it like that? What problem are you really trying to solve?

Comment: @Dave Newton I am trying to find a solution that the application can provide a UI or someway to let user write in configuration into the properties file, forget to mention it is OK to let user restart the application.

Comment: I edited my answer below. Is this you are looking for?

Answer (score 1):

You may use Spring's dynamic language support.

http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/dynamic-language.html

It allows you to change your app's behavior at runtime.

Below is an answer for the **updated question**.

Assuming you are using Spring MVC, IMO you can implement your configuration setting page as a part of Spring MVC app.

However, if you stick to implementing regular JSP that is executed outside the Spring MVC framework, you can put a JSP file to any location in your webapp (except under the WEB-INF directory) and execute the JSP directly. (e.g. `http://yourhost/yourcontextroot/foo.jsp`.)

To make above work, you may need to configure the `<url-pattern>` for the DispatcherServlet like below to have servlet container handle a jsp request:

```
<servlet>
  <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
  ...
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can;t dynamically change a propertty.

So you will need to store in a database via an application.

But you need a permanent database url,to store the other settings.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

`PropertyPlaceholderConfigurator` for this.

```
db-conf-server1.properties
db-conf-server2.properties
db-conf-server3.properties
db-conf-server4.properties
```

What you have to do is, dynamically data put into this file and load the appropriate file when you server will start.

I have done same in one of my project, in which what ever configuration you have to used that parameters you needs to pass in server configuration.

Let me know if you need further details.